# PHP's array_key_exists - is using @ on the array access a viable alternative?

Tags: php, performance

I'd like to know whether simply using PHP's error suppression syntax is a faster and simpler alternative to array_key_exists where it is not certain that a particular key exists.

That is, instead of:

```
if (array_key_exists($array, $key)) {
    $myval = $array[$key];
    [... do something with $myval ...]
}
```

Simply use:

```
if ($myval = @$array[$key]) {
    [... do something with $myval ...]
}
```

Seems like this is both more efficient and less wordy, but perhaps it introduces subtle problems or edge-cases that I'm not seeing yet.

What are the potential problems with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW you can also use `isset()`.

The error suppression operator in PHP also slows it down a lot, to about half the usual speed.

And finally you will eventually run into a case where you are supressing errors, and discover that you typoed and `$aray` doesn't exist either, which you will never even find out since you are blocking all errors.

Comment: Mostly true, but `isset` will fail if the value in the array is `null`, whereas that would be accepted by `array_key_exists`.

Comment: Hadn't realized there was a speed penalty for using error suppression... seems a bit counter-intuitive that suppressing errors would be slower!

Comment: Good blog post on the performance penalty of @ error suppression here: http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem is that the value in the array could be falsy.

If `$array[key] === false` then the first case would enter the `if` but the second case would not.

Comment: Good point.  As it happens, I rarely ever make arrays of anything other than objects, so it's not something I've run into (or likely will)